# when we start pipeline , Have to give input to pipeline as integer value & that has to be used in pipeline as varible

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a scenario that, when we start a build it should ask to enter an integer value and that value has to be used as variable in pipeline .

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [Jenkins syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters), an integer parameter doesn't exist.
Instead, you would have to define the parameter as a string:

```
parameters {
    string(defaultValue: null, description: 'This is an integer', name: 'INT_PARAM')
}
```

Then parse it to int (assuming you are using Groovy):

```
if (env.INT_PARAM.isInteger()) {
    int value = env.INT_PARAM as Integer
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, make sure to accept it as an answer